# JavaScript - textContent implementation

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I am currently working on a HTML Calculator as part of the Odin Project.

I have encountered a weird behavior of .textContent: Here is my Code snippet from JavaScript:

```
//---output is a HTML tag at which the input of the user should be entered-------------------------------
const output=document.querySelector('.Output');

//------I store the input (pressed keys) into an array
let input=[]
//-------------------------------------------------

//--------------keybord support--------------------
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.key != "+" || e.key !="-" || e.key !="*" || e.key !="/") {
        let internalVariable = 0;
        input.push(parseInt(e.key));
        internalVariable=input.join('');
        output.innerHTML=internalVariable;
    }   

    if (e.key=="+") {
        console.log(typeof e.key,input)**-> Test if condition works**
    }
```

Problem is: Whenever I press + button, I still get an output (NaN) and I get an entry(NaN) into my input-array whoch should not happen.

Did I miss understood text.Content ?

Comment: You ask about `textContent`, but your code does not use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if (e.key != "+" || e.key !="-" || e.key !="*" || e.key !="/") {
```

Let's simplify it to just two conditions:

```
if (e.key != "+" || e.key !="-") {
}
```

This will always be `true`. If the key is `+`, then it will not be `-`, satisfying the second part. If the key is `-`, then it will not be `+`, satisfying the first part.

Use a string of keys instead, and check if the pressed key is included in it.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if ('+-*/'.includes(e.key)) {
```

Or, another option is to check if the key is a digit.

```
if (/\d/.test(e.key)) {
```

Demo:

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.Output');

const input = []
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (/\d/.test(e.key)) {
    input.push(parseInt(e.key));
    internalVariable = input.join('');
    output.innerHTML = internalVariable;
  } else {
    console.log('do something when a non-digit was pressed');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="Output"></div>
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)